# How to target an after of an element with two classes with SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I know that when you want to target a div with two classes with SCSS, it should be done like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="item active">...</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.item {
  &.active {
   /* enter code here */
  }
}
```

But when I want to target an element's after, what then? As in with CSS:

```
.item.active:after {
/* enter code here */
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can do it in a few ways

a. This you should use if you want to add some styles to the `.active` class also.

```
.item {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  &.active {
    &:after{
      content: "aaa";
    }
  }
}
```

or

b. This you should use if you want just to add some styles to the `:after` pseudo-element if `item` has class `active`

```
.item {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  &.active:after{

      content: "aaa";

  }
}
```

see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/72r9syj6/)

Comment: Thanks, Mihai! This is it!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.item {
   &.active {
     &:after {
     /* enter code here */
     } 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.item {
    &.active {
        /* enter code here */
        &:after{
            /* enter code here */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to read the following page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - Apply some context to your answer, It's a good practice to provide some direction for the asker.